# WS_EX_LAYERED windows and avoiding copying from GPU to CPU

Tags: winapi

On Windows 7 onwards how do you ensure layered windows via the WS_EX_LAYERED window style do not incur a performance hit of copying data back from the GPU to CPU for hit testing?

From what I have read this optimisation only seems possible if the full window region lets mouse hits pass right through, or fully blocks them.  But how do you *specifically* ensure this behaviour in both of these cases?

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for. On recent Windows (8+), you don't need layered windows at all do do fancy things as Direct Composition (win32) and Windows.UI.Composition (winrt) do the job. They do the job because they have deep intimacy with Windows Desktop Manager (DWM) who's really the boss of composing your desktop using low level DirectX tech.

Comment: That is why I specifically said Windows7 onwards.  It's a very straightforward question that doesn't deserve a down vote.

Comment: I still don't understand the question and it looks like I'm not the only one (I didn't downvote if that's what you think). "Windows 7 onwards" doesn't really mean anything as precisely many things changed with Windows 8 (and Windows 7 is not supported any more), possibly for layered windows as well. What makes you think there are performance hits? in what case precisely? do you have reproducing code with real issues?

Comment: A layered window whose contents are on the GPU will be copied to the CPU for hit testing as noted here for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/june/windows-with-c-high-performance-window-layering-using-the-windows-composition-engine .  But I cannot find anywhere that states what specific windows styles or windows message handling behaviour for example that will avoid such a copy in the two cases I state.

Comment: *what specific windows styles or windows message.. will avoid such a copy*,AFAIK, there is no such windows style or message. According to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/december/windows-with-c-layered-windows-with-direct2d#the-architecture-problem): *In the case of layered windows, the bitmap must travel back to system memory since User32/GDI resources involve both kernel-mode and user-mode resources that require access to the bitmap*

Comment: So there is nothing that can be done in the two cases I mention (where the copy would be unnecessary) to avoid that copy?  It's still going to do it if all hit testing is disabled on the window (ie all click passing through) for example?  In which case that would be the answer.

Comment: Does this behavior have an actual performance impact on your program?

Comment: Does avoiding a potentially unnecessary copy of what could be a 3840 x 2160 x 32bit RGBA bitmap (~31 MB) from GPU to CPU every frame seem like a good idea?  I think so.

Comment: "Does avoiding a potentially unnecessary copy of what could be a 3840 x 2160 x 32bit RGBA bitmap (~31 MB) from GPU to CPU every frame seem like a good idea? I think so."
On Windows 7 though. Most people writing desktop applications right now do not spend a lot of time worrying about an operating system from 10+ years ago.

Comment: I think you will find that's actually not true, and also highly depends on your industry.  There are still a lot of developers that want to ensure, or won't off the cuff easily disregard compatibility with 25% of the desktop market.  By your logic MacOSX/Linux desktop developers should just give up too.  But that's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: We suggest to report or discuss on the FeedBack Hub.